# Ignore case while doing xsl:sort

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to sort a XML doc using xsl:sort

My requirement is to ignore case while doing the sort.  xsl:sort have a case-order attribute which helps specify upper-first or lower-first, which is of no help for me.

I also tried using translate function, something like this :

```
<xsl:sort select="translate('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',sortOn)" order="ascending" />";
```

dint work either.

Ideas are appreciated.

Comment: what version of xslt are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The parameters to your translate function are in the wrong order.

```
<xsl:sort select="translate(sortOn 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz','ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')" order="ascending" />
```

This function is defined as follows in the [XPath spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/):

> Function: string translate(string,
>   string, string)
>
> The translate function returns the
>   first argument string with occurrences
>   of characters in the second argument
>   string replaced by the character at
>   the corresponding position in the
>   third argument string.

Comment: There is a missing comma after "sortOn" in the code FYI

Answer (score 2):

How about `<xsl:sort select="lower-case(sortOn)"/>` ?

Comment: `lower-case` is unavailable in XSL 1.0.